# I wonder, Is there a way to store the chef logs created by hosted chef server(https://api.chef.io) - chef - client?

Tags: chef-infra

I want to store the logs generated by hosted chef-server(https://api.chef.io). I don't find a way to direct the logs to chef workstation when executing a knife bootstrap command.

I know i can redirect console output logs to a file.

Is there an option to copy/redirect the logs to the specified location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have access to the logs from Hosted Chef.

Comment: Thanks very much @coderanger for giving me the information